# How to write a XSLT for my XML which might involve multiple for loops

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement and I'm struggling with it. I'm new to XSLT just trying to figure out what is what.

In this requirement I have a XML, under every report node there is a Business Tag. My XSLT should be in such a way that I need to get all the View/Initiate/Rescind/Approve/Cancel & Correct security linked to this Business in a column by column fashion.(Well I'm not sure how put a correct question).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report_Data>
<Report>
    <Business>Electronic</Business>
    <View>
        <Security>View A</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View B</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View C</Security>
    </View>
    <Initiate>
        <Security>Initiated A01</Security>
    </Initiate>
    <Initiate>
        <Security>Initiated Z01</Security>
    </Initiate>
</Report>
<Report>
    <Business>Adjustment</Business>
    <View>
        <Security>View CE</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View MFK</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View VW</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View KKL</Security>
    </View>
    <Initiate>
        <Security>Initiated 004</Security>
    </Initiate>
    <Initiate>
        <Security>Initiated M16</Security>
    </Initiate>
    <Approve>
        <Security>Approve Manager</Security>
    </Approve>
    <Approve>
        <Security>Approve AXE</Security>
    </Approve>
    <Approve>
        <Security>Approve LKL</Security>
    </Approve>
</Report>
<Report>
    <Business>Purge Event</Business>
    <View>
        <Security>View Administrator</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View Auditor</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View Developer</Security>
    </View>
    <Initiate>
        <Security>Initiate Administrator</Security>
    </Initiate>
    <Initiate>
        <Security>Initiate Developer</Security>
    </Initiate>
    <Cancel>
        <Security>Cancel HR</Security>
    </Cancel>
    <Cancel>
        <Security>Cancel Administrator</Security>
    </Cancel>
    <Cancel>
        <Security>Cancel Developer</Security>
    </Cancel>
    <Cancel>
        <Security>Cancel Initiator</Security>
    </Cancel>
</Report>
<Report>
    <Business>Generated Event</Business>
    <View>
        <Security>View Process Administrator</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View Developer</Security>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Security>View Auditor</Security>
    </View>
    <Rescind>
        <Security>Rescind Process Administrator</Security>
    </Rescind>
    <Rescind>
        <Security>Rescind Developer</Security>
    </Rescind>
</Report>
<Report>
    <Business>Expense</Business>
    <Rescind>
        <Security>Rescind Sr Developer</Security>
    </Rescind>
    <Cancel>
        <Security>Cancel developer</Security>
    </Cancel>
    <Cancel>
        <Security>Cancel Sr Developer</Security>
    </Cancel>
    <Correct>
        <Security>Correct ADMIN</Security>
    </Correct>
</Report>
</Report_Data>
```

Output:

```
Business,View,Initiate,Rescind,Approve,Cancel,Correct
Electronic,View A,Initiated A01,,,,             
Electronic,View B,Initiated Z01,,,,             
Electronic,View C,,,,,                  
Adjustment,View CE,Initiated 004,,Approve Manager,,     
Adjustment,View MFK,Initiated M16,,Approve AXE,,        
Adjustment,View VW,,,Approve LKL,,      
Adjustment,View KKL,,,,,                    
Purge Event,View Administrator,Initiate Administrator,,,Cancel HR,  
Purge Event,View Auditor,Initiate Developer,,,Cancel Administrator, 
Purge Event,View Developer,,,,Cancel Developer, 
Purge Event,,,,,Cancel Initiator,   
Generated Event,View Process Administrator,,Rescind Process Administrator,,,            
Generated Event,View Developer,,Rescind Developer,,,            
Generated Event,View Auditor,,,,,                   
Expense,,,Rescind Sr Developer,,Cancel developer,Correct ADMIN
Expense,,,,,Cancel Sr Developer,
```

Please any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you literally want the output to show like that or structure the XML for a two-dimensional row and column spreadsheet/database table/data frame import?

Comment: @SasukeSurendra: Please note the alternate solution posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not simple at all. If you're new to XSLT, this is not the best project for you to take on.

Now, if I understand the requirement correctly, you want to combine all the values of a report that have the same position into a single row, and keep doing that until you run out of values in all categories. This could be accomplished using a recursive named template:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:text>Business,View,Initiate,Rescind,Approve,Cancel,Correct&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Report">
        <xsl:call-template name="write-rows"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="write-rows">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <!-- write to output -->
    <xsl:value-of select="Business"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="View[$i]/Security"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Initiate[$i]/Security"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Rescind[$i]/Security"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Approve[$i]/Security"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Cancel[$i]/Security"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Correct[$i]/Security"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt; count(View) or $i &lt; count(Initiate) or $i &lt; count(Rescind) or $i &lt; count(Approve) or $i &lt; count(Cancel) or $i &lt; count(Correct)">
        <xsl:call-template name="write-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank You Michael . This is exactly what I was looking out for.Yeah I know this new project is kinda difficult for me. But the expectations are very high since I was good performer in my previous. Doing XSLT for 2 months now , learning bits and pieces now and then. Thanks for your Help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure where(site details) can i  find all these examples, , if you would let me know then you have my heart filled thanks.

Comment: "*where(site details) can i find all these examples*" I am afraid I don't know what you refer to.

Comment: Nevermind about that Michael ... Thank You very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple problem, and a good learning exersize for XSLT. You did not specify the XSLT version (which is often super important when you post an XSLT question on StackOverflow). I have assumed XSLT 2.0, but in this case, the solution applies equally well to XSLT 1.0.

This tiny stylesheet transforms your given sample input document to your expected output document.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>Business,View,Initiate,Rescind,Approve,Cancel,Correct&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Report_Data/Report/View" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="View">
  <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::View) + 1" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(../Business,',',.,',',../Initiate[$i],',',../Rescind[$i],',',../Approve[$i],',',../Cancel[$i],',',../Correct[$i],'&#x0A;')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Learning Note

Eschew pull style transforms (`xsl:for-each` etc) where possible, especially when you are learning. In general, push style transforms (like leveraging templates) will give you simpler, more efficient and more maintainable solutions. Push is better for learning too, because it is more in harmony with the spirit of XSLT. XSLT is meant to be functional, not procedural.

## Correction

At first I though that the most populous child was always View, and my first solution depends of that. Thank's to Michael's comment, I notice that that is incorrect. So we need to make a slight adjustment of computing which child of Report is the most populous for that Report. I am also assuming that there is always exactly one Business element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>Business,View,Initiate,Rescind,Approve,Cancel,Correct&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Report_Data/Report" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report">
  <xsl:variable name="child-node-names" select="('View','Initiate','Rescind','Approve','Cancel','Correct')" />
  <xsl:variable name="max-children" select="max( for $n in $child-node-names return count( *[local-name() eq $n]))" />
  <xsl:variable name="most-populous-child" select="(for $n in $child-node-names return $n[ count( current()/*[local-name() eq $n]) eq $max-children])[1]" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name() eq $most-populous-child]" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="View|Initiate|Rescind|Approve|Cancel|Correct">
  <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() eq local-name(current())]) + 1" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(../Business,',',../View[$i],',',../Initiate[$i],',',../Rescind[$i],',',../Approve[$i],',',../Cancel[$i],',',../Correct[$i],'&#x0A;')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also, you could do another alternate solution with xsl:for-each-group/xsl:sort. For interest, here is the grouping solution...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>Business,View,Initiate,Rescind,Approve,Cancel,Correct&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Report_Data/Report" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="* except Business" group-by="local-name()">
   <xsl:sort select="count(current-group())" data-type="number" order="descending" />
   <xsl:variable name="group" select="position()" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[$group eq 1]" />
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="View|Initiate|Rescind|Approve|Cancel|Correct">
  <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() eq local-name(current())]) + 1" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(../Business,',',../View[$i],',',../Initiate[$i],',',../Rescind[$i],',',../Approve[$i],',',../Cancel[$i],',',../Correct[$i],'&#x0A;')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*This is a very simple problem*" You might want to reserve that statement until your result matches the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ok, I can see I am missing the lines that correspond to empty views. Fix is coming ..